# I need help using phpqrcode to make qr codes

Tags: php, qr-code

I've been playing with the phpqrcode library but I can't get it to correctly output an image. The library just doesnt seem to be working and I've tried configuring it different ways.

What I'm trying to do is display the qrcode when the user presses a button I have set up on my page. I have yet to get the library to output an image and would like to get it to work before my hair falls out.  I've followed the directions in the documents and have tried to use both types of methods to output the qrcode to the screen with no luck.

If someone could post a usable sample that works that would be awesome.

Comment: sure it does....maybe your just to lazy to answer lol

Comment: It doesnt need to i just need a working sample to compare to what ive done already

Comment: -110 to the lazy question trolling point collectors :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really straightforward

```
include_once(LIB.'phpqrcode/qrlib.php');
QRcode::png("something to incode", false, QR_ECLEVEL_H, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response :) Ive tried using that exact simple couple lines of code to no avail. All I get is one of those broken image marks. Im setting up fiddler to see what kind of info is comming back. Is there anything else I would need to insert into the page to get that to work.

Comment: Make sure your debug is on display_errors="on" and error_reporting=E_ALL to see if its not a config issue. I can't recall if I had to adjust any of the library files or not (I don't believe I had to, though)

Comment: Also check to make sure the CACHE dir exists in phpqrcode/qrconfig.php (or set it to false)

Comment: ok Im gonna check for that right now.

Comment: in the qrconfig.php file the CACHE dir is set to true. Do i need to set up the _FILE_ with my own file in  define('QR_LOG_DIR', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)

Comment: All I did was make sure the **cache** directory exists at phpqrcode/cache and make sure it's writable.

Comment: Im not seeing that in my system anywhere....I would guess thats a problem. How do I create a cache file.

Comment: It's just a directory that needs to be at phpqrcode/cache.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the help :) Some one pointed out to me that I had entered extra blank spaces below my last ?> in my php code which i hadnt noticed.

Comment: Just to add here (now 2013) I found that I had to create a directory called 'temp' with CHMOD 777 permissions - so that the PNG file could be written to disk. Hope this helps someone in the future coming from Google like me!

Comment: @Paul it would be nice if you told us what directory you created the 'temp' folder under...